# ArcGIS for Server or its alternative?

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, web-service

I am trying to develop a GIS web application. I am using ArcGIS for desktop as the database. I  need to use existing ArcGIS Restful services but also need to publish some new services. I think that ArcGIS for server would be the best choice for me. But I cannot afford it. 
And I want to know:

1. If there is a free lightweight version of ArcGIS for server?
2. Does a open source alternative such as GeoServer have APIs to use ArcGIS Restful services?

Comment: When you say "using ArcGIS for desktop as the database", do you mean you are wanting to create map services from a file geodatabase?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to what you are asking, is that there is no other geoserver which has the exact same REST API as ArcGIS Server. There are several license-levels for ArcGIS Server, and the price differs accordingly.

Now coming to solving your actual problem. You say that `"I need to use existing ArcGIS Restful services"`. I would ask why?

Other FOSS servers like Geoserver & MapServer, have their own API/protocol called the WMS which is used in web maps. It is an OGC standard, and many clients/libraries including Openlayers, Leaflet, and even ArcGIS Web APIs support it.

Depending on your requirements, you could serve out your data as a WMS/WFS service and consume it in a JavaScript Web App.

Comment: e.g. I'd like to use the Geocode/Geoprocessing restful service provided by ArcGIS

Comment: @user1101148 If your requirements are that you need to use ArcGIS Server, then tautologically you'll have to use ArcGIS Server

Comment: Have you considered WPS as alternative to GP services?

Comment: I suspect that an [**OGC GeoServices REST specification**](http://www.opengeospatial.org/projects/groups/gservrestswg) may have been more along the lines of what you are after but that looks to be getting a lot of [**resistance**](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/discuss/2013-May/thread.html#11599).

Answer (score 0):

My company just released CloudSpatial which implements the same open specification as ArcGIS Server ([GeoServices REST Specification](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/geoservices-rest-spec.pdf)) It is very easy to setup and much less expensive than ArcGIS server. For more info check - http://www.cloudspatial.com/gisserver/

Comment: They had to change their name due to a conflict, look for https://www.bluespatial.com now.

Answer (score 0):

My company released SoftBox Geoserver which implements ESRI compatible Feature Services, Geocode Services, Network Analyze Service, ...

The solution includes a set of core web services and tools for configuring and publishing data.
MS SQL Server, Postgresql, MySQL are supported.
Contact with me for more information.

There is also support for ui components, plug-ins and functions of external developers through the UI of the system

https://greatsoftbox.ru/solutions